# What is the best file format when fetching an image via url on android

Tags: android, svg

I need to fetch some images from my server. I'm wondering if SVG is the best format on android.
What are the benefits of using png/jpg?
Is there some security issues on SVG?

Thanks!

Comment: I depends... You need to be more specific. Do you have an example of an image? How large is it, is it a photo, vector graphics etc. It is difficult to give a not-opinion based answer without this information.

Comment: Vector graphics. It can be 25x25 to 600x600